# Java Swing - Why is this no longer draggable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, listener

Yesterday I was trying to make a draggable, undecorated JPanel, it was working perfectly and then today I loaded up the project and it was no longer working (I have no idea why this would happen because I did save everything properly).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

This is the source code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class CustomBubble extends JFrame {

    public int xMouse;
    public int yMouse;

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public CustomBubble()
    {
        super("CustomBubble");
        setSize(150,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setVisible(true);

        pnl.addMouseMotionListener(
                new MouseAdapter()
                {
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        int x = e.getXOnScreen();
                        int y = e.getYOnScreen();

                        setLocation(x - xMouse, y - yMouse);
                    }

                });
        pnl.addMouseListener(
                new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                        xMouse = me.getX();
                        yMouse = me.getY();
                    }
                });

        add(pnl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CustomBubble gui = new CustomBubble();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual line from the program? Because it won't compile: `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Yea, that's in there. It compiles for me. The only problem I have is that when the panel shows up, I can no longer click and drag it around the screen.

Comment: This probably won't matter, but what if you change it to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`?

Comment: I changed it to JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE and it doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on my computer and got it to work. Normally the `setVisible(true);` statement should be the very last thing that you do. So just move that statement down after the `add(pnl);` call, and you should be good.

```
...
add(pal);
setVisible(true);
} // end of constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine. I have tried this code in my computer . Not giving any error . Works fine..

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author ****
 */
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public int xMouse;
    public int yMouse;

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public Test()
    {
        super("CustomBubble");
        setSize(150,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setVisible(true);

        pnl.addMouseMotionListener(
                new MouseAdapter()
                {
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        int x = e.getXOnScreen();
                        int y = e.getYOnScreen();

                        setLocation(x - xMouse, y - yMouse);
                    }

                });
        pnl.addMouseListener(
                new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                        xMouse = me.getX();
                        yMouse = me.getY();
                    }
                });

        add(pnl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test gui = new Test();
    }
}
```